# Can a Sites Guest User have a license in the Sbox?

Tags: appexchange, app, force.com-sites

Our app requires a license for the Sites Guest User. I do not see this in sandbox. A sites guest user cannot have a license in sbox? Is there a workaround? something I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

As long as there is a site available for the org, you will have a 'guest' license.  This license type is not visible under the same section as the rest of the licenses, but you can verify if you have a site by going to Setup > Develop > Sites >

Answer (score 1):

Force.com Sites are supported in sandbox. I'm not sure why you aren't seeing a license. Does the organization that the sandbox from have sites?